# Custom content animations in UIStoryboardSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been writing a mini framework for animating custom segues in iOS. It works well in iOS 7, but as soon as I started testing in iOS 8 all hell broke lose.

The reason I'm doing this is that I want to animate the view's content, not the frame. So far I think all segue animations I've seen animate the frame, like flipping, curling, and so on. Instead, I want to animate the constraints in the view. That is, buttons up, down, to the left, etc.

I did it by creating a custom segue class, `HySegue`, which polls the view controllers for presenting and dismissing animations, if they conform to given protocols. So far so good.

I now need to run the animations, but the problem is where. Here's what I'm doing:

```
    UIView * sourceView = sourceViewController.view;
    UIView * destinationView = viewControllerToPresent.view;

    // Force the source view to layout
    [sourceView addSubview:destinationView];
    [sourceView layoutIfNeeded];
```

So my idea is to add the destination view as a subview of the source view, run the animation, revert the previous changes, and finally present the destination view controller. Here it is:

```
    UIViewController * parentViewController = viewControllerToDismiss.parentViewController;
    UIView * destinationView = destinationViewController.view;

    // Break the view hierarchy that was setup earlier
    [destinationView removeFromSuperview];

    // When presenting in a UINavigationController stack, push the destination view controller
    if ([parentViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

        [(UINavigationController *)parentViewController pushViewController:destinationViewController
                                                                  animated:NO];
    }

    // Otherwise use the standard method
    else {

        // Present the destination view controller
        [viewControllerToDismiss presentViewController:destinationViewController
                                              animated:NO
                                            completion:nil];

        [viewControllerToDismiss willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [viewControllerToDismiss.view removeFromSuperview];
        [viewControllerToDismiss removeFromParentViewController];
        [viewControllerToDismiss didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    }
```

Again, this works well in iOS 7, but in iOS 8 I get:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <HyRegistrationNavigationController: 0x7bf540c0>
```

So it seems I'm trying to display a view controller before the previous one finishes displaying. How can I solve this? Ideally, there would a third view and view controller involved, which would serve as the container for the transition, but I can live without it.

Comment: Do you get this error both with, and without a navigation controller? Also, how are you calling the methods to present the view controller? Are you calling them from the completion block of the animation?

Comment: Also, how is viewControllerToDismiss defined? Are the controllers involved in this segue embedded in a custom container controller?

Comment: My apologies for the delay, I was in a meeting. Yes, I get the same result without using a navigation controller. Yes, I am calling the methods to present the view controller in the completion block. There are two transitions involved. When each animation finishes that call `setTransitionFinished:`. When both transitions are finished the destination view controller is presented

Comment: Both view controllers are defined by the segue. The segue has source and destination view controllers. `viewControllerToDismiss` is the source view controller. But no, I do not have a third view controller nor view involved in the process, although I would much prefer! If I could avoid adding the destination view as a subview of source view I think it would be ideal. But if I can't, I don't think it would be a big deal